# How to create custom layouts in websphere portal 8

Tags: websphere-portal

Please tell the exact procedure to create a custom layout in websphere portal 8 such that it can be used for newly created pages.

Can't understand online content for doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems are you experiencing? What online content are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_layout_templates_wp8&content=pdcontent

Comment: Read that. Didn't understand what should i do for that. I just need to create a custom layout using which can create a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the [documentation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=prodDoc)?

You can copy one of the [layout-templates](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_layout_templates_wp8&content=pdcontent) and start working from there.

Comment: I don't need the already existing layouts pal. Just need to create one. Don't find a way to do so.

Comment: What Udo means, and what the documentation you linked to suggests, is to create a new layout by first making a copy of an already existing one. Then make changes to the copy to suit your needs. This is typical way to create a new theme, layout or skin.

Comment: It is directly told in the first paragraph. "To add a layout template .."